# SONY TV as Display / Monitor

Tags: raspbian-stretch, hdmi, display, pi-3b+, driver

Background:
I have successfully used pi-3b+ to display on LG LED TV, New model Sony 4K LED TV.

Requesting your support:
The year 2011 SONY 40NX710 model is showing blank (No desktop / text-console).

Following are the trials I have done in /boot/config.txt:-

```
hdmi_safe=1
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_group=0
hdmi_mode=1
hdmi_drive=2
config_hdmi_boost=9
dtparam=audio=on
hdmi_ignore_cec_init=1
hdmi_ignore_cec=1
```

It did NOT work ...

---

*Right now, I do NOT have access to LG LED TV or New model Sony 4K LED TV.*

---

I have used following to get further information we may require:-

1 of 4:

```
#List of CEA-supported modes:
/opt/vc/bin/tvservice -m CEA &> BASHRC_cea.txt
Content of the file BASHRC_cea.txt  Group CEA has 16 modes:
           mode 1: 640x480 @ 60Hz 4:3, clock:25MHz progressive
           mode 2: 720x480 @ 60Hz 4:3, clock:27MHz progressive
           mode 3: 720x480 @ 60Hz 16:9, clock:27MHz progressive
           mode 4: 1280x720 @ 60Hz 16:9, clock:74MHz progressive
           mode 5: 1920x1080 @ 60Hz 16:9, clock:74MHz interlaced
           mode 6: 720x480 @ 60Hz 4:3, clock:27MHz x2 interlaced
           mode 7: 720x480 @ 60Hz 16:9, clock:27MHz x2 interlaced   (prefer) mode 16: 1920x1080 @ 60Hz 16:9, clock:148MHz progressive
           mode 17: 720x576 @ 50Hz 4:3, clock:27MHz progressive
           mode 18: 720x576 @ 50Hz 16:9, clock:27MHz progressive
           mode 19: 1280x720 @ 50Hz 16:9, clock:74MHz progressive
           mode 20: 1920x1080 @ 50Hz 16:9, clock:74MHz interlaced
           mode 21: 720x576 @ 50Hz 4:3, clock:27MHz x2 interlaced
           mode 22: 720x576 @ 50Hz 16:9, clock:27MHz x2 interlaced
           mode 31: 1920x1080 @ 50Hz 16:9, clock:148MHz progressive
           mode 32: 1920x1080 @ 24Hz 16:9, clock:74MHz progressive
```

2 of 4:

```
List of DMT-supported modes:
/opt/vc/bin/tvservice -m DMT &> BASHRC_dmt.txt

Content of BASHRC_dmt.txt
Group DMT has 4 modes:
           mode 4: 640x480 @ 60Hz 4:3, clock:25MHz progressive
           mode 9: 800x600 @ 60Hz 4:3, clock:40MHz progressive
           mode 16: 1024x768 @ 60Hz 4:3, clock:65MHz progressive
           mode 35: 1280x1024 @ 60Hz 5:4, clock:108MHz progressive
```

3 of 4:

```
Show TV current state:
/opt/vc/bin/tvservice -s &> BASHRC__current_state.txt

Content of BASHRC_current_state.txt
state 0x12000a [HDMI CEA (16) RGB lim 16:9], 1920x1080 @ 60.00Hz, progressive
```

4 of 4:
Dump more detailed information from your monitor:

```
/opt/vc/bin/tvservice -d BASHRC_edid.dat
```

Edid.dat parser

```
/opt/vc/bin/edidparser BASHRC_edid.dat &> BASHRC_edid_parsed_details.txt
  1 Enabling fuzzy format match...
  2 Parsing BASHRC_edid.dat...
  3 HDMI:EDID version 1.3, 1 extensions, screen size 160x90 cm
  4 HDMI:EDID features - videodef 0x80 !standby !suspend !active off; colour encoding:RGB444|YCbCr422; sRGB is not default col    ourspace; preferred format is native; does not support GTF
  5 HDMI:EDID found monitor name descriptor tag 0xfc
  6 HDMI:EDID monitor name is SONY_TV
  7 HDMI:EDID found monitor range descriptor tag 0xfd
  8 HDMI:EDID monitor range offsets: V min=0, V max=0, H min=0, H max=0
  9 HDMI:EDID monitor range: vertical is 48-62 Hz, horizontal is 14-70 kHz, max pixel clock is 150 MHz
 10 HDMI:EDID monitor range does not support GTF
 11 HDMI:EDID found preferred CEA detail timing format: 1920x1080p @ 60 Hz (16)
 12 HDMI:EDID found CEA detail timing format: 1280x720p @ 60 Hz (4)
 13 HDMI:EDID established timing I/II bytes are 21 08 00
 14 HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 4, 640x480p @ 60 Hz in established timing I/II
 15 HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 9, 800x600p @ 60 Hz in established timing I/II
 16 HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 16, 1024x768p @ 60 Hz in established timing I/II
 17 HDMI:EDID standard timings block x 8: 0x8180 0101 0101 0101 0101 0101 0101 0101
 18 HDMI:EDID found DMT format: code 35, 1280x1024p @ 60 Hz (5:4) in standard timing 0
 19 HDMI:EDID parsing v3 CEA extension 0
 20 HDMI:EDID monitor support - underscan IT formats:yes, basic audio:yes, yuv444:yes, yuv422:yes, #native DTD:0
 21 HDMI:EDID found CEA detail timing format: 1920x1080p @ 50 Hz (31)
 22 HDMI:EDID found CEA detail timing format: 1280x720p @ 50 Hz (19)
 23 HDMI:EDID found CEA detail timing format: 1920x1080i @ 60 Hz (5)
 24 HDMI:EDID found CEA detail timing format: 1920x1080i @ 50 Hz (20)
 25 HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 31, 1920x1080p @ 50Hz
 26 HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 16, 1920x1080p @ 60Hz
 27 HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 20, 1920x1080i @ 50Hz
 28 HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 5, 1920x1080i @ 60Hz
 29 HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 19, 1280x720p @ 50Hz
 30 HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 4, 1280x720p @ 60Hz
 31 HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 18, 720x576p @ 50Hz
 32 HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 17, 720x576p @ 50Hz
 33 HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 22, 1440x576i @ 50Hz
 34 HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 21, 1440x576i @ 50Hz
 35 HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 3, 720x480p @ 60Hz
 36 HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 2, 720x480p @ 60Hz
 37 HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 7, 1440x480i @ 60Hz
 38 HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 6, 1440x480i @ 60Hz
 39 HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 1, 640x480p @ 60Hz
 40 HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 32, 1920x1080p @ 24Hz
 41 HDMI:EDID found audio format 2 channels PCM, sample rate: 32|44|48 kHz, sample size: 16|20|24 bits
 42 HDMI:EDID found audio format 6 channels AC3, sample rate: 32|44|48 kHz, bitrate: 640 kbps
 43 HDMI:EDID found HDMI VSDB length 8
 44 HDMI:EDID HDMI VSDB has physical address 3.0.0.0
 45 HDMI:EDID HDMI VSDB supports AI:yes, dual link DVI:no
 46 HDMI:EDID HDMI VSDB deep colour support - 48-bit:no 36-bit:yes 30-bit:yes DC_yuv444:yes
 47 HDMI:EDID HDMI VSDB max TMDS clock 225 MHz
 48 HDMI:EDID HDMI VSDB content type support: game|cinema|photo|text
 49 HDMI:EDID found Video Capability DB length 2
 50 HDMI:EDID video capability: CE:3 IT:2 PT:3 QS:1
 51 HDMI:EDID filtering formats with pixel clock > 162 MHz or h. blanking > 1023
 52 HDMI:EDID best score mode initialised to CEA (1) 640x480p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 25 MHz (score 0)
 53 HDMI:EDID best score mode is now CEA (1) 640x480p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 25 MHz (score 61864)
 54 HDMI:EDID best score mode is now CEA (2) 720x480p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 27 MHz (score 66472)
 55 HDMI:EDID CEA mode (3) 720x480p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 27 MHz has a score of 66472
 56 HDMI:EDID best score mode is now CEA (4) 1280x720p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 74 MHz (score 4635592)
 57 HDMI:EDID DMT mode (4) 640x480p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 25 MHz has a score of 18432
 58 HDMI:EDID CEA mode (5) 1920x1080i @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 74 MHz has a score of 3273832
 59 HDMI:EDID CEA mode (6) 1440x480i @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 27 MHz has a score of 45736
 60 HDMI:EDID CEA mode (7) 1440x480i @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 27 MHz has a score of 45736
 61 HDMI:EDID DMT mode (9) 800x600p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 40 MHz has a score of 28800
 62 HDMI:EDID best score mode is now CEA (16) 1920x1080p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 148 MHz (score 5398248)
 63 HDMI:EDID DMT mode (16) 1024x768p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 65 MHz has a score of 47185
 64 HDMI:EDID CEA mode (17) 720x576p @ 50 Hz with pixel clock 27 MHz has a score of 66472
 65 HDMI:EDID CEA mode (18) 720x576p @ 50 Hz with pixel clock 27 MHz has a score of 66472
 66 HDMI:EDID CEA mode (19) 1280x720p @ 50 Hz with pixel clock 74 MHz has a score of 3617160
 67 HDMI:EDID CEA mode (20) 1920x1080i @ 50 Hz with pixel clock 74 MHz has a score of 2732360
 68 HDMI:EDID CEA mode (21) 1440x576i @ 50 Hz with pixel clock 27 MHz has a score of 45736
 69 HDMI:EDID CEA mode (22) 1440x576i @ 50 Hz with pixel clock 27 MHz has a score of 45736
 70 HDMI:EDID CEA mode (31) 1920x1080p @ 50 Hz with pixel clock 148 MHz has a score of 4232360
 71 HDMI:EDID CEA mode (32) 1920x1080p @ 24 Hz with pixel clock 74 MHz has a score of 124532
 72 HDMI:EDID DMT mode (35) 1280x1024p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 108 MHz has a score of 103643
 73 HDMI:EDID preferred mode remained as CEA (16) 1920x1080p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 148 MHz
 74 HDMI:EDID has HDMI support and audio support
 75 /opt/vc/bin/edidparser exited with code 0
```

---

Not knowing where to go ... as a last resort, I have approached this community .. please help!

Comment: Are you sure the fault is with the pi??? If it worked with two other TV's then I would suspect the issue may lie with this third TV your now using. Are there other hdmi ports on it you can try or other devices you can plug into the TV to see whether they show up (or not) as well.

Comment: try `hdmi_group=1` `hdmi_mode=16` `config_hdmi_boost=6` and remove the `_cec_` entries - also try a different HDMI cable as well as the other 3 HDMI ports on the TV

Comment: TV ports are gone bad ... thank you @rohtua